# "looking for the accessible text of the novel" vs. "looking for an accessible text of the novel"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I've come to think today whether the use of the definite article in the context of the
following post is correct:

> Having trouble understanding *Pride and Prejudice*? Being visually impaired, are you looking for **the** accessible text of the novel?
> If your answer to any of the above questions is yes, then you may find my annotated version of the novel useful.

***The** accessible text ...* sounds more natural to me than ***an** accessible text of ...*
Nevertheless, as there could be many versions of the text, i.e. editions, prints, etc., I am not quite sure whether the usage of the definite article here would be correct.

I was trying to resolve my doubts with [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+the+accessible+text+of+%2C+for+an+accessible+text+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), but the tool has not proved to
be very useful in this particular case.

Comment: What is the context? A publisher offering an 'accessible' version of the novel? If so, they would want to make it seem as though theirs is the "one to have", not "one of many". Also 'the' can be used when there are many, to stress that it is the best known, or most used. "This is **the** accessible version".

Comment: @Weather The context is of the blog post in which its author recommends their annotated version of the novel that is available for free on their website.

Comment: So, why would they imply there might be other versions available? Compare "Thank you for finding the accessible version of P&P!" with "You have found an accessible version of P&P but there might be other versions which you prefer."

Comment: @Weather I thought about 'an' in this context because at the beginning of the post its reader does not now what the post is about - the post is not titled, it is published on Facebook. The reader of the post is not necessarily someone who has found the publication already, they may be just a friend or the follower of the author. I added one more sentence to the blockquotes of my question so that the context is clearly shown.

Comment: What you say is generally correct, but not inviolable. For example in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string) discussion about what "empty string" means (in computer technology) they refer to "the empty string" which is at variance with the general rule.

Comment: Before you argue about the details, please note the general use is incorrect. How you can discuss details before this is corrected I do not know

Comment: In context, "__the__ accessible text" implies that there is only one such version of the novel. This is highly unlikely, as the publisher is free to produce the novel in as many forms as the market will support. Therefore, I would say "an" would be the correct article.

Comment: "... **an accessible version of the text** ..."

Comment: If it was in copyright there might be only one accessible text (the official version authorised by publisher and author), but for a work of that age, it seems likely there would be more than one - so maybe they are used to writing about newer books. "The empty string" isn't a valid comparison because on an abstract level there's only one empty string, just like there's the number zero, the empty set, the set of all integers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accessible text is a generalisation not a specific. In fact in the sentence quoted both "a" (an) or "the" would be incorrect. In fact accessible text of the novel is also incorrect. "The novel in accessible text" or an "accessible text edition of the novel, Pride and Prejudice ".

> I am looking for **a** copy of **The** Mongolian language accessible text edition of **the** novel, Pride and Prejudice.

or

> Being visually impaired, I would like **a** novel in accessible text, if you have any?

Comment: Please note that In my opinion "accessible text" is just another of these new buzz words or worst a sales con. And probably in this case a misleading one. What I suspect they mean  are "Large print version" If you are using a e-reader the size of print is manipulated by the reader not the publisher.